# Want to know Difference b/w Titan Query and ES query

Tags: titan

What is the difference between query:

I want to find all data with city name `XYZ`,

1. When I use `Titan` graph query like `xyzCityVertex.query().direction(IN).label("hasCity").iterator()`

2 .When I directly execute `Elastic Search query` without titan like `cityField:"XYZ"`

Yes one is Graph query other is plain ES query. But for the moment forget that and imagine i have set of data stored using Titan and i want to run both query for the same purpose.

Are both same internally and performance wise?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to "forget" that one is a vertex query and the other is a ES query.  That is what makes them so markedly different.  I would say they also represent possibly different use cases.  You typically use a "graph query" or "ES query" for the same thing to find a vertex or set of vertices to start a traversal from.  A "graph query" will likely be faster than an ES query but a graph query should have high selectivity in that it typically should not return "lots of things." An ES query has less restriction that way and is better suited to return lots of things.

In your example, you show a "vertex query" which means that you've already found your vertex of interest and want to traverse from that.  Traversals over incident edges (such as your example shows) should be very fast and I would assume that it would be faster than a similar lookup of the same adjacent vertices with "graph query" or "ES query".

In other words:

```
g.V('city','XYZ').in('hasCity').cityField
```

would be faster than a graph query where cityField was indexed to return lots of vertices:

```
g.V('cityField','XYZ')
```

and would be faster than the equivalent ES query over `cityField`

Comment: if we use titan to search based on `city field` inside ES. it will also be using same ES query internally right? so if i use `ES directly on index titan field` then it should be less complicated to equivalent `ES+Titan` query or just `vertex query`

Comment: Do you mean if you use the ES API "directly" it will be less "complicated" to doing the same query using Titan's API that reaches through to ES?  and what do you mean by "complicated"?  are you still referring to performance?

Comment: yah I mean using "ES API" to access titan vertices and "complicated" i used for performance. There r many cases where titan query is not sufficient in itself so use of ES comes in the picture

Comment: Well, if Titan query is "not sufficient" then you have little choice but to use the ES API directly i suppose.  I'm not sure if doing that will provide you a gain in performance though.  I suppose it depends on your data and schema design.   I don't think there is much more I can offer than to say that you have to try it and see what your results are.